# nvme ssd, doesn't show up upon installing

Tags: system-installation, gparted, nvme

I recently bought a [Lenovo Legion Y530](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y530-15ich) and put an Adata XPG sx8200 SSD into it, but Ubuntu installation (both 18.04 and 19.10) can not see it, whilst it works perfectly with Windows 10. My BIOS SATA mode is set to AHCI and the BIOS is UEFI.

How may I troubleshoot this?

[boot info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oZlT.jpg)

Comment: is your bios set to Legacy or UEFI? Please click [edit] and add that information to your question.

Comment: Many need UEFI update & then SSD firmware update, even if new. Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907

Comment: I have both the UEFI and SSD frimware up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with some help I was able to figure out the answer. Basically my SSD turns into some sort of power saving monde so you have to add nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200 to GRUB and that's it.